# Selenium - TestNG - Running groups using Code

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm making a GUI for use of TestNG, currently I have a dropdown box which uses then allows you to press a button which I want to run a group of tests

```
  @Test(groups = {"Group1"})
  public void Test()
  //Test Data

  @Test(groups = {"Group1"})
  public void Test2()
  //Test Data


  @Test(groups = {"Group2"})
  public void Test3()
  //Test Data
```

I'm currently running this code via the run configurations and calling the group to run there.

Is there any way I can do this via a button press so the user can press run Group1 and then run Group2 in an executable program?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a synthetic testng.xml in the Java code using the group inputs. But this might get messy with large size testng.xml.

You can also call testng from the command line (Have to figure out this from your GUI code) which has many parameters available like include groups, exclude groups etc etc.

```
java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...] -groups "grp1,grp2"
```

Refer to [http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng}

Comment: I'm relatively new to TestNG and have been using a GUI linked to JUnit tests until now, is there any way I can simply write some code like

      if(Option1){
      Run this Group
      
I've seen a lot of information about using xml's etc but I've honestly not had the chance to look into this nor would I know how to even call the XMLs in via button press. Got a deadline at work so any advice you could give would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @NGrabham You should use Krishnan Mahadevan solution. It is much easier and absolutely tailor-made for your requirement. You just set a system property with the group choices and access it inside Beanshell using java.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of BeanShell feature that TestNG provides for doing this. You can define a JVM argument that reads the value set using the drop down selected option and then run it.
You can read more about using Beanshell and TestNG from [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/) blog post that I created.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code? Im not able to use BeanShell on my environment but instead have access to XMLBeans if this is similar, I've made an xml and I can run it, just not via the code.

Comment: @NGrabham - Did you take a look at the blog post that I shared ? It has samples in it as well.